# Не работают поля ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему не срабатывают поля ввода?

Вот код:

```
<div id="mmd-flight-widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function initWidget() {
    var options = {
        layout: {
            theme: "momondo"
            , width: "300"
            , height: "250"
        },
        airports: {
            origin: "",
            destination: ""
        },
        settings: {
            openNewWindow: true,
            domain: "www.momondo.ru",
            source: ""
        }
    };
    var settings = options.settings;
    var airports = options.airports;
    var layout = options.layout;
    var encoding = null;
    onWidgetLoad = function (f)
    {
        f("mmd-flight-widget", {
            searchForms: [{
                type: 1,
                searchURL: "http://[DOMAIN][PATH][QUERY]" + (!!settings.source ? "&source=" + settings.source : ""),
                openNewWindow: settings.openNewWindow,
                currency: settings.currency,
                segments: [
                    {
                        airports: [
                            { code: airports.origin || "" },
                            { code: airports.destination || "" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        airports: [
                            { code: airports.destination || "" },
                            { code: airports.origin || "" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });
    };
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    scr["src"] = "http://" + settings.domain + "/widget/searchform/v1.0/?dimensions=" + (layout.width && layout.height ? (layout.width + "x" + layout.height) : "generic") + "&types=1&callback=onWidgetLoad&theme=" + layout.theme;
    var tag = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (tag && tag.length)
    {
        tag = tag[0];
        tag.appendChild(scr);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Код вставляю в html и открываю браузером, всё нормально, но поля ввода, куда и откуда, не срабатывают.
P.S. Ожидаю такого же действия как на jsfiddle. То есть при клике на инпут он становится активным и при наборе букв выпадает меню с подходящими вариантами. Возможно ли это из за того что скрипт располагаю не на сервере? Скрипт в html файле, файл просто находиться на компьютере и открываю его браузером.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, какое действие вы ожидаете от вашего скрипта и какое получаете. Так будет гораздо проще помочь вам найти ответ

Comment: Еще добавьте фрагмент HTML с данными полями

Comment: Посмотрите какие ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: [ваш код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3duepj0n/1/) отлично работает, единственное - поиск аэропорта долгий, поэтому после того как набрали хотя бы три буквы, нужно дождаться ответа от сервера, в котором будут подходящие аэропорты которые покажутся в выпадающем списке

Comment: Ожидаю такого же действия как на jsfiddle. То есть при клике на инпут он становится активным и при наборе букв выпадает меню с подходящими вариантами. Возможно ли это из за того что скрипт располагаю не на сервере? Скрипт в html файле, файл просто находиться на компьютере и открываю его браузером.